# Is it possible to install Windows 10 to a larger drive while putting the boot loader and hibernation file on a different, smaller, faster drive?

Tags: windows-10, hibernate, bootloader

I am working on a new desktop build and am trying to maximize both performance and stability.  I have a RAID 5 array for my system volume that will have Windows installed on it and my data.  I have a small RAID 0 array of NVME drives that I want to use as a swap drive.

Ideally I'd like to have both the pagefile and hibernation file on this drive, but I realize that the hibernation file needs to be on the bootable drive.  My question is thus, is there a way to install Windows in a similar manner to a dual boot where the NVME array is the bootable partition, but only contains the bootloader, pagefile and hibernation file, with the rest of the OS actually being loaded from the RAID 5 array.  This way, if the RAID 0 array fails, all I have to do is rebuild the bootloader and all is good to go again.

Comment: Hibernation file must be on the system disk.  Only the page file can be on another disk.

Comment: Sure, but is it loaded from the system or the bootloader?  I'm not 100 percent clear on what component actually restores the hibernation file.  I would assume it restores memory state before a full kernel boot or is that incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because RAID 5 and RAID 0 are two different virtual hard disks, the bootable partition and the system must be on the same physical disk. The hibernation file and the system must be on the same logical disk, so I am afraid that your idea may not be possible.